# Cómo concatenar Razor con javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#

Tengo el siguente código

```
var indice = 1;
var dtypes = '@Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode(Html.DropDownList("1").ToString())';
return dtypes;
```

Lo que quiero es concatenar la variable indice con el dropDownList. Algo Así

```
var indice = 1;
var dtypes = '@Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode(Html.DropDownList(""+indice+"").ToString())';
```

Pero al momento de compilar me dice que la variable indice no existen en el contexto actual.

Qué puedo hacer?

Comment: Probablemente la variable este fuera de scope, pero no estoy seguro ya que no adjuntaste un contexto claro. Saludos.

Comment: El problema es que tu variable `indice` existe en el script de tu página, no en el contexto del servidor `C#`. O por lo menos eso es lo que se puede deducir con el poco código que nos estás presentando. Por favor, incluye más información.

Answer (score 0):

Ya que estamos hablando de JS, podemos usar las template strings para interpolar el valor dinámico de variables dentro de una cadena de texto.

Quedando así:

```
let indice = 1;
let dtypes = `@Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode(Html.DropDownList(${indice}).ToString())`;
return dtypes;
```

- Envolvemos entre comillas simples invertidas o backticks el texto completo
- La variable dinámica la podemos pasar con la sintaxis de: `${variable}`